# How to find the average values of specific columns based on position

Tags: r, dataframe, average

Hi I am trying to think of a method of finding the row means of specific columns based on their position in the data frame. The data frame in question looks like this.

dput(head(df)):

```
structure(list(UUO_miRNA_O.1 = c(7.32066744158959, 3.31345009504282
), UUO_miRNA_O.2 = c(7.43053887142984, 3.23035600235404), UUO_miRNA_O.3 = c(7.68570216473529, 
3.29381316430644), UUO_miRNA_3.1 = c(7.34325738531531, 3.67473069667518
), UUO_miRNA_3.2 = c(7.3048971830047, 3.69280901141072), UUO_miRNA_3.3 = c(7.41661827643479, 
3.06893743175378), UUO_miRNA_3.4 = c(7.43802624369909, 3.43504336111569
), UUO_miRNA_7.1 = c(7.10631159462831, 3.72163460891437), UUO_miRNA_7.2 = c(6.81674699622009, 
3.89466659628421), UUO_miRNA_7.3 = c(6.78711965034826, 3.94771804243868
), UUO_miRNA_7.4 = c(6.54435389593729, 4.14166831423149), UUO_miRNA_14.1 = c(6.84918460025062, 
3.85693219667159), UUO_miRNA_14.2 = c(6.68019422109324, 3.69409920554401
), UUO_miRNA_14.3 = c(6.40959585449136, 3.64231329240453), UUO_miRNA_14.4 = c(6.59104287861439, 
3.64138476787772)), row.names = c("mmu-let-7a-1-3p", "mmu-let-7a-2-3p"
), class = "data.frame")
```

The data has differing numbers of replicates. I would like to know a method of getting the row means for each gene, per experiment type.

Currently I am using this type of code to get my ideal output.

```
apply(df[1:3], 1, mean)
apply(df[4:7], 1, mean)
apply(df[8:11], 1, mean)
apply(df[12:15], 1, mean)
```

I have tried turning this into a loop but with little success due to the inconsistent number of repeats. Also, this code is not the most pleasant, so if there is a method in R or a function that could be suggested I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
vec_start <- c(1, 4, 8, 12)
vec_end <- c(3, 7, 11, 15)

mapply(function(x, y) rowMeans(df[seq(x, y)]), vec_start, vec_end)

#                   [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#mmu-let-7a-1-3p 7.478969 7.37570 6.813633 6.632504
#mmu-let-7a-2-3p 3.279206 3.46788 3.926422 3.708682
```

Comment: Hi this worked well too. It takes into consideration the position of the columns so I think this answered the given question precisely.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `sub` to strip the names after the dot. Loop over the new unique names and calculate the `rowMeans` of the subset of your data frame that matches each name, i.e.

```
sapply(unique(sub('\\..*', '', names(df))), function(i) rowMeans(df[grepl(i, names(df))]))

#                UUO_miRNA_O UUO_miRNA_3 UUO_miRNA_7 UUO_miRNA_14
#mmu-let-7a-1-3p    7.478969     7.37570    6.813633     6.632504
#mmu-let-7a-2-3p    3.279206     3.46788    3.926422     3.708682
```

Comment: That worked very nicely. '\\..*' means it is splitting at the '.' correct? Need to make  in case forget what this code does.

Comment: Exactly. I added an explanation

Comment: I did `sapply(split.default(df, sub(".*_(.*)\\..*", "\\1", names(df))), rowMeans)`

Comment: @RonakShah Not surprising :D I was debating between `split.default` and `sapply`

Comment: @RonakShah the split.default method worked but it also re-arranged the output order to 14, 3, 7, 0. The Sub method kept the original column order.